# A recursive identity for the sum of divisors

Tags: number-theory, summation, divisor-sum

Let $(n,k)=\gcd(n,k)$ and $(n,l,k) = \gcd(\gcd(n,l),k)$, $\sigma(n)=$ sum of divisors of $n$. My question is, how the "ugly" identity, which I can prove it is true, can be "simplified" in presentation?:

$$\sigma(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\sigma((n,k))}{n-1}+\frac{n}{n-1}\sum_{l=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{(n,l)}\frac{\sigma((n,l,k))}{(n,l)}$$

Note, that the interesting part for this identity is, that we compute $\sigma(n)$ using only numbers $x<n$ and $\sigma(x)$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: An easy start would be swapping all $k$ and $l$ just in the second summation so that the sums can be combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swapping your use of $k$ and $l$ in the second term gives

$$\sigma(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\sigma((n,k))}{n-1}+\frac{n}{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{l=1}^{(n,k)}\frac{\sigma((n,k,l))}{(n,k)}$$

Multiplying by $n-1$,

$$(n-1)\sigma(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\sigma((n,k))+n\sum_{l=1}^{(n,k)}\frac{\sigma((n,k,l))}{(n,k)}\right)$$

By taking the sum up to $k=n$ rather than $k=n-1$ we get

$$n\sigma(n)+\sum_{l=1}^{n}\sigma((n,l))=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\sigma((n,k))+n\sum_{l=1}^{(n,k)}\frac{\sigma((n,k,l))}{(n,k)}\right)$$

Then after getting rid of the redundant terms and dividing both sides by $n$ we have

$$\sigma(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{l=1}^{(n,k)}\dfrac{\sigma((n,k,l))}{(n,k)}$$

Comment: thanks. thats how derive the identity. but now you use $\sigma(n)$ to compute itself. so it is not recursive any more

Comment: The identity uses the factorization of $n$ implicitly, so it's not useful for computing $\sigma(n)$ efficiently. I don't really understand the point of complicating the identity.

Comment: It was meant to be recursive. thats all

Comment: In that case I don't know what to do other than exactly as you've done by subtracting the $\sigma(n)/n$ term from both sides and dividing by $(1-1/n)$. Edit: actually I have an idea. I'll get back to you after I've eaten.

Answer (score 0):

I think, one way to present such a recursive formula in a nice way, is the classical one, given by

$$\sigma(n) = \sigma(n-1) + \sigma(n-2) - \sigma(n-5) - \sigma(n-7) + \sigma(n-12) +\sigma(n-15) + \cdots +$$
Here  $1,2,5,7,...$ is the sequence of *generalized pentagonal numbers* $\frac{3n^2-n}{2}$ for $n = 1,-1,2,-2,...$ and the signs are repetitions of $1,1,-1,-1$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I know the formula you mentioned from Wikipedia and have read the Euler article on this. Do you mean, that those formulas are equivalent?

Comment: Did you test this for small $n$? For example, for $n=10$ we have $\sigma(10)=\sigma(9)+\sigma(8)-\sigma(5)-\sigma(3)$, in fact, $18=13+15-6-4$. What about your formula for $n=10$?

Comment: I think they can not be equivalent, since in Eulers formula we have $-$ sign, whereas in the formula above there is no $-$ sign.